# Stack overflow in Windows subsystem (yet not in Console)

Tags: c++, windows, stack-overflow

Again, title says it all.
I just converted my Console application to a Windows application, and after I got over the main roadbumps, I ran into one not so easily solved. (By me, at least)

```
int mmsend()
{
while (true) {
    char mmessage[512];
    std::cin.getline(mmessage, 512);
    if (strlen(mmessage)<1) {
        GoToXY(0,23);
        mmsend();
    }
    char msendbuf[512]="Client> ";
    strcat(msendbuf,mmessage);
    msend(msendbuf);
    if ((strncmp(msendbuf,"Client> /",9)) != 0) {
        printm(msendbuf,FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    }
    GoToXY(0,23);
    for (int sp=0; sp<(strlen(msendbuf)); sp++) {
        std::cout<<" ";
    }
    GoToXY(0,23);
}
return 0;
}
```

When it was still in the console subsystem, this piece would work fine. Now every time I execute, I leave with a stack overflow. Fun.
I feel like I might be overlooking an obvious answer considering the name of this site...
:)

Thanks for your help,
-P

Comment: The stack overflow is the result of `mmsend()` calling itself too many times, probably because `std::cin.getline()` isn't blocking. But is that the GUI-converted version of the method, because you still use std::cin & std::cout ?

Comment: Freshly converted. I've never played around with a GUI in C++ before, which would explain my ignorance. I'll play around with it, thanks. This would also explain why the receiving function kills itself...

Comment: A Windows GUI application is message-based. Let's say you have a window. There's a multiline, read-only [edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) meant to display the output of commands, taking most of the height of the window, except for another single-line edit control at the bottom where the user inputs commands. You would then act upon characters sent to the input edit, looking for the WM_KEYDOWN message with wParam=VK_RETURN to know the user has pressed the Enter key to validate his input.

Comment: Get rid of that unsafe C string stuff and use `std::string`.

Comment: Hmm.. That's a bit over my head for now, but I will definitely come back to this later. Another, perhaps easier, thing to tackle while I have you here would be simply displaying a message window with a variable text. If you could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @chris I'm aware of this supreme instability. The only reason I haven't switched over to `std::string` yet is a matter of nostalgia. This was the first C++ program I ever wrote... I remember thinking for hours on how to put together my array and came up with this monstrosity... Good days. :) And I guess if it works it works. (That's not to say I won't make the switch in the near future though...)

Comment: Unfortunately, `strcat(msendbuf,mmessage);` is crying out, "Buffer overrun!"

Comment: @chris Believe it or not, I'm a security enthusiast myself, and I was so excited when I recognized that. Now, I obviously don't have the skills to go around exploiting that on my own, but... One day... It is my goal to do so... This program is for personal use anyway.
However, I'm convinced. Tomorrow I shall make the change.
Sorry if I'm coming across as a know it all, but seriously thank you all for your input and assistance. I love this community. :)